# How to define the heat current in an isotropic continuum material

Tags: continuum-mechanics, thermal-conductivity, phonons

I'm doing a FDTD (finite difference time domain) simulation of an isotropic continuum material. And I have several questions.

1. How do you define the energy transferred through an isotropic continuum material by thermal vibrations (i.e. the heat current)? I've seen the definition for a lattice ([Hardy 1963](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.132.168)), so I'm guessing it's similar for a continuum material but maybe simpler since the potential is known.
2. I'm doing a FDTD simulation of an isotropic continuum material using the method in [Kelly et al.](http://library.seg.org/doi/abs/10.1190/1.1440605), and I'd like to get the heat current from that. For molecular dynamics simulations, there isn't an agreed upon way to do this ([Guajardo-Cuéllar 2010](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/132/10/10.1063/1.3358338)). Is there a known, more straightforward method for these FDTD simulations?
3. Do you know of any good resources on this topic? I haven't seen it in may continuum mechanics books.

Comment: In continuum mechanics, heat conduction is usually modelled using Fourier's Law. In a continuum simulation, you are usually concerned with length scales far larger than an atomic lattice where heat transfer no longer resembles wave propagation. The thermal conduction wiki page has a good treatment of the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction

Comment: Tyler, I'm aware of that, but that's not what I'm interested in. Waves carry energy, and I'd like to know how much energy elastic waves are carrying. You can substitute 'energy' for 'heat' in the question if you'd like. FWIW, when Debye derived his expression of the heat capacity of a material, he treated the material as an isotopic elastic material (linear, isotopic dispersion relation) with a cutoff frequency corresponding to a two atom wavelength. So I'm not the first person to look at heat this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is pretty straightforward. Power is the force dotted with velocity, so it should make sense that the energy current (a power in a direction) takes a similar form. For an elastic medium, this vector is the product of the stress tensor with the velocity vector ([source](http://inside.mines.edu/~rsnieder/Ch1-7-1.pdf)). The result is the heat flux (current) -- the equivalent of the Poynting vector in electrodynamics.

EDITED FOR CLARITY AND TO FIX A MISTAKE

Comment: I don't understand what was the question and what is the answer....If you are interested in heat transport in a continuum medium, one can (nowadays) hardly do better than Fourier's law as suggested by Tyler Olsen. All the subtleties arising from phonon-phonon scattering or phonon-electron scattering etc.. you name it, are encapsulated in the heat diffusion coefficient (or tensor) of your material. You may also have to account for convection in liquids and thermal dilation of your materials but I don't see how heat would generate say acoustic waves.

Comment: There is a vector to describe the amount of energy being transferred by a wave and the direction the energy is flowing in. For electromagnetic waves, that's the Poynting vector. I was wondering what the equivalent vector was for elastic waves, and that's the question I answered. Perhaps I should have used the phrase "energy current" or "energy flux" instead of "heat flux", but the latter is a valid phrase often used with phonons, which are equivalent to elastic vibrations in the long wavelength limit. The phonon or elastic wave heat flux has the same meaning as the heat flux in Fourier's law.

Comment: "I don't see how heat would generate say acoustic waves." Would you agree that phonons are an important component of heat? Phonons _are_ waves, and many are called acoustic (see wikipedia). They are called acoustic because in the long wavelength limit, they behave exactly like acoustic vibrations of a continuum material. I hope that helps put the pieces together.

Comment: My point is not here. My naive thoughts on it are that the phonon contribution to heat transfer is already encapsulated in the diffusion coefficient of the Fourier law. There are simple hand waving calculations (in the Kittel for instance) on how to account for the phonon contribution to the heat transport. In such simple descriptions, one imagines a phonon gas where elementary acoustic waves are going in all possible directions at very small scales.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions and understand what you are saying, but I am not using Fourier's law because it is inadequate my purposes -- full stop. I have good reasons to be interested in elastic waves for heat transfer, but I'm not going to put a grant proposal in a stackexchange comment, so you'll just have to trust (or ignore) me. If you're curious, here are three papers along the line of my interest that use elastic waves to model heat flow: http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.87.115502 http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.80.195408 http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3684973

Comment: thanks for the references. If I understand well, your aim is to figure out the transmission coefficient for your material and you want to do so by looking at the Green function of a wave equation characteristic of ballistic phonons. Is that it? The reason I was surprised with the method you described at first, is that there was no sign of statistics in it. But as far as I understand the statistical aspect of it comes from a particular formula for the conductance. Or do you actually do something different from the PRL?

Comment: I'm interested in the same goals (learning about transmission through a rough wire), but I'm lazy and am interested in a simpler, numerical approach. I'm considering something more like an equilibrium Molecular Dynamics (MD) simulation, where they often find a heat current through the structure and then extract a thermal conductivity using the Green-Kubo formula (which allows you to get the conductivity by looking at the correlations in the heat current over time). One of the papers in the question gives some more infromation on the MD technique: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3358338